# PhpStorm Code Completition wrong menu color

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-completion

I recently updated my PhpStorm to 2021 version, but I having a problem with code competition menu. On Darcula theme (dark theme) that menu is impossible to read anything. Any chance to change the menu color without change theme?
Systems Windows 10, x64 version.

[image: CodeCompletitionMenu]

I find the solution changing:
Open Settings:
Find Editor|Color Scheme|General|Popups and Hints|Documentation. Thanks LazyOne for the hint.

Comment: Broken code completion color quite likely would be coming from custom color scheme. In that case please open the scheme file and change `parent_scheme="Default"` to `parent_scheme="Darcula"`, e.g.: `<scheme name="xxx" version="xxx" parent_scheme="Darcula">`. Obviously, this needs to be done when IDE is closed. Any better? In either case: see comments in [IDEA-263380](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-263380)

Comment: Change the parent_scheme don't fix the problem (my fila has parent_scheme="Darcula"), but on provided link I find the solution, changing ´´´Settings >
Find Editor|Color Scheme|General|Popups And Hints|Documentation´´´ background color. Thanks.